# Unable to send data from javascript to spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
var edit = $('#edit .fr').html();
```

I am sending this value to spring controller using AJAX .

```
ajaxRequest('POST', 
            JSON.stringify(data), 
            'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
            makeURL('submit') +
                    '?edit' +
                    edit,
            okFunc, 
            errorFunc);
```

Now in my spring controller, I get the value of edit as null.

```
@RequestParam(value="edit", required=false)String  edit
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to change: '?edit' in '?edit='

Comment: thanks nik for the help

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Your error could be at the part where you build the URL. Looks like the equal sign is missing:

```
makeURL('submit') + '?edit=' + edit,
```

Comment: The url posted is  correct for other variables, it is working correctly. The problem is comming with .html()

Comment: I believe other variables are being sent in your post body. This is the only variable in the url query string.

Comment: Open your chrome in debug mode, and in the console evaluate the value of the expression: "makeURL('submit') + '?edit' + edit". Pick up the result and use POSTMAN or some other tool to test your spring endpoint. Check if it works. I doubt it will because of the missing '='

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo mistake